# Why does the fill factor in SQL Server default to 0 (100%)?

Tags: sql-server, index, best-practices, fill-factor

I understand fill-factor, pages and index structure and I therefor understand why a 100% fill factor is a rare best practice. So why does it default to 0 (or 100% ) by default? Why not 90 or 95?

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just throwing out a few suggestions here as to why Microsoft would do this:

1. They have geared their default to be best possible OLAP performance (less page reads with a fill factor of 0/100)
2. They are assuming that `INSERT`ed data will most likely be at the end of the table, making the extra space per page useless
3. They are assuming that typically `UPDATE`d data will not lengthen row data very often, causing a page split

This is just guessing here.  The only people that can really answer that question accurately is the SQL Server team themselves.

Comment: Right, these seem like sensible theories, and are far more likely to be appropriate for the typical customer than picking some arbitrary fill factor where, in a lot of cases, you're guaranteed to permanently waste space on a page.

Comment: I can't believe I got an answer that I can agree with. I didn't expect there existed a reasonable answer but your #2 and #3 points are very sensible. Thanks!

Comment: @NTDLS no problem, glad to help.